# Can someone please explain Preg_Match_All

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to understand preg_match_all in php.
A friend and I run a small site for fun with a few friends, to practice coding mostly, and we added a section a while back that contains the code to strip any source of it's images:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.anyrandomwebsite.com');
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$html, $result);
```

which we pretty much just found online, and couldn't make too much sense of it, but I understand that it finds any instances of image tags on a page and puts them into an array.

Now, I'm trying to create a code that searches a source for any links on a page (so anything starting with 'http') and preferably only something that ends in a specific extension (i.e. .net, or .zip)

But, I can't figure out how to write the pattern. I've tried learning Regex, but based on what my friend's have told me, the code used to find image tags doesn't follow normal rules, and they don't fully understand it either.

Basically, I am looking for someone to please write a preg_match_all that can find links on a page, and then to please explain to me WHY it works, and also explain how the above code works (preferably, character by character in the pattern part)

Thank you very much to anyone who responds to this!

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Did you try reading the fracking [**MANUAL**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), as it probably explains it better than most will be able to?

Comment: I started with the Manual, yeah. It made a lot less sense. (especially because it wasn't specific in it's definitions, for example, it doesn't mention that $pattern is regex, which I had never had to use before, so it took more research to figure that out. Then I spent awhile learning regex, most guides to it I have found seem to skip steps, and I can never get a level of understanding that explains this code.

Comment: For instance, in this code: '/<img[^>]+>/i' I get that it starts by searching for a string beginning with '<img', but I don't understand why the '[^>]' is there, because I don't see what searching for any character except '>' accomplishes. I also don't see how it is finding the end of the tags.

Comment: `match the character <img literally`, then `match any character that is not ">"`, then `between one and unlimited times, giving back as possible`, then `match the ">" character literally`. It is becoming complicated because you **think** it is complicated. Just go through the rules and it is self explanatory.

Comment: Thank you itachi, I think one of my original problems had been that I had seen a page earlier that said that `+` meant `OR`, which had thrown me off. I also didn't realize that `+>` meant to keep checking until a `>` was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the regex you have:

```
/      # Starting regex delimiter
<img   # Match <img
[^>]+  # Match one or more characters that aren't a >
>      # Match a >
/      # Ending regex delimiter
i      # Case-insensitive option
```

How does it work?

Imagine what an `img` tag looks like. It starts with `<img` and ends with `>`. So once we've identified an `<img` tag, we need to match everything until the nearest `>`.

That means we need to match as many characters as we can, as long as they are not a `>`. And that's exactly what `[^>]+` does. Since there needs to be at least one of those characters (`<img>` is not legal), we use a `+` instead of the "zero or more" `*`.

You might see a problem here: What if the tag *does* contain a `>` somewhere, e. g. in an attribute? And there you have one of the reasons why using regexes to parse HTML is fraught with peril.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I finally figured out my code, and this was a tremendous help!
My code is 

`preg_match_all('/http(.+)\.zip/i', $html, $result);`

I was having a problem for awhile where I was trying to use `[.+]` instead of `(.+)` due to a small misunderstanding, but I'm all good now.

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Careful, `.+` will cause problems if you have more than one link on one line.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this?
I just figured that `(.+_)/zip` meant that it would always continuously search and pull every character until it found '.zip', and to my current understanding, that's pretty much the only way to grab entire links.

Comment: It's difficult. There's not going to be a perfect solution; links are so variable in their structure that you won't find a 100 % reliable regex. One step in the right direction would be to use `\S` (non-whitespace characters) instead of `.` because as far as I know, links can never contain actual whitespace. So `/http(\S+)\.zip/i` should be a little better.

Comment: Okay, I'll make that change. Is there any reason why using the `.+` is so bad specifically? (I get that the more specific `\S+` is better, as it is more specific, but I want to know what could be wrong with `.+` for a better understand, and to prevent future problems).

Comment: Imagine `"http://firstlink.zip this is no link http://secondlink.zip"`. The regex with `.+` would have matched the entire string at once. Nothing is keeping `.+` from matching beyond the first link.

Comment: Okay, I thought it would end at the first `.zip`.
Thank you.